# Why is focus triggered on Windows but not on macOS in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I use Electron 10 and I noticed a different behavior of events between Windows and macOS. In my example I register a variety of `focus` and `drag/drop` events.

On Windows, when I drag a file or directory over the Electron BrowserWindow, I get the drag/drop console outputs AND the `focus` event. On macOS the `focus` event is not triggered. Should the behavior be the same between on both systems? See the code below:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
{ 
    console.log("focus"); // < Why is this printed on Windows...
    // ... but not on macOS when a directory or file is dragged onto the window?

}, false);

window.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) 
{ 
    console.log("dragover"); // correctly triggered on both Operating Systems
}, false);
```

Comment: read the issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19920

Comment: I am not sure that's exactly the same because they report the window doesn't come to the foreground, which isn't the case here. The problem is that the focus event is triggered on Windows but not on macOS.

Comment: you should read the full issue , on same  issue 19920 read this https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/issues/335

Comment: Now I see, it's the other way around. I assumed the behavior of macOS is correct whereas Windows is correct.